# What's the best way to provide a large amount of code in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-limit

While answering [PHP / Mime Types - List of mime types publically available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519393/php-mime-types-list-of-mime-types-publically-available/14279336#14279336), I received the following error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered

What's the best way to work around this? I ended up just linking to the ~1,000-line PHP array the solution requires, but is there a better way?

Comment: This is *such* an edge case IMO. Whilst link only answers aren't permitted, there's also no point including a list of half of the MIME types, so I'm not sure on the best behaviour. Adding it as two separate answers would work, but it's not ideal...

Comment: The question asked for a publically available list of MIME types, so your second link was actually an adequate answer. You could additionally have explained how to turn that into a PHP array.

Comment: the best way to "work around" this (to be precise, the definitive way to present the code at sites like Stack Exchange) is **[SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/165773 "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example")**

Answer (score 6):

We typically want answers with high [information density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). A question that requires you to come up with > 30,000 characters of original code is *very, very* likely to be Not-A-Real-Question.

In this specific instance, your answer doesn't need to be more than 30,000 characters. It should suffice to provide a link to the the list of MIME types at the Apache website, along with the code you used to parse the original list into PHP. This contains the exact same amount of information as the snippet you were trying to paste, captured in a much smaller volume of text.

Comment: +1 - the only sane way to do this. SO isn't suited to contain huge lists. A link to the reference resource is sufficient.

Comment: What does "NARQ" mean?

Comment: @gerrit It's an acronym for "Not A Real Question".