# Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics, graphs

I recently came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22756/242678), which states (emphasis mine):

> ..The problem that became evident was that **people who want to learn how to write a good question and people who can't write a good question are mutually exclusive groups.**
>
>  <sub>- [Eric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/95589/eric)</sub>

*Naturally*, [I had to see if I could graph this](http://xkcd.com/523/), so I wrote [this query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220780/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-vs-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts?DaysNewUser=7&BadScore=0&GoodScore=5) to get some data.

By defining *users who can't write good posts* (hereafter referred to as *bad authors*) as all users without a cumulative positive post score, but with at least one post, after a week of account creation, and *users who want to write good posts* (hereafter referred to as *informed authors*) as all authors who received either an Informed<sup>1</sup> or Analytical<sup>2</sup> badge within the same time period, I obtained (for [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)) the following chart:

[image: Bad authors]

By my definition of *bad* and *informed authors* (which are narrow, I know, but the best I could think of possible with SEDE), the two groups are indeed almost mutually exclusive. In fact, on SO, **only 3% of *bad authors* are also *informed***.

This is especially striking when comparing to *users who can write good posts* (hereafter referred to as *good authors*) defined as all users with a cumulative post score of at least 5 after a week of account creation. On SO, about **20% of *good authors* are also *informed***:

[image: Good authors]

Therefore, it seems that at least to the extend of my limited definitions, [Eric](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22756/242678) was right. I thought I had to make people aware of this.

*Any questions and comments are welcome.*

---

**Footnotes**

1. Informed badge: *Read the entire about page.*
2. Analytical badge: *Visited every section of the FAQ (retired).*

Comment: For clarification, when you say a good author has a cumulative post score of 5+ after a week of account creation, do you mean people who have earned 5+ points in their first week, or accounts that are at least a week old with 5+ cumulative score?

Comment: Why is the Death Star that's orbiting Yavin so much bigger than the one that's orbiting Endor? (But seriously: interesting investigation.)

Comment: @Troyen It's here defined as *people who have earned 5+ points in their first week* to make it equivalent to the definition of *good authors*.

Comment: There is a problem with using the account creation date in that any user that lurks around and only participated a few weeks/months after creating their account will not count as being a good/informed author. Do you think that this could have an effect on your statistics?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That is true. I've made the assumption that the large amount of these users can be extrapolated. Another more inclusive (and difficult) method would be to use the first ~5 posts of a user, no matter the timeframe. However, this might also introduce noise as the users would have more time to learn how to write a good question by simply reading a lot of other posts - but it would probably be worth try.

Comment: Good authors don't need to be informed because, if you have a brain, pretty much everything in the Help Centre is frakking obvious.