# Diamonds (♦) break the automatic hyperlink parser

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Questions like:

- [My question was deleted by Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/my-question-was-deleted-by-community)♦
- [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-)♦-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions
- [Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-)≠-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts

well, you can see there.  The diamond (and other problematic Unicode characters) in the title breaks the automatic prettification of internal question links.

This becomes a bit more of an issue when one wants to link to an answer.  For example [Diamonds (♦) break the automatic hyperlink parser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242571/diamonds-)♦-break-the-automatic-hyperlink-parser/242572#242572 *should* link to Martijn's answer, but, it doesn't (tangent, but a different issue is that https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242572/213963 which is the share link doesn't auto-prettify unless the userid part is removed - one keeps having to manually remove things to get the auto prettify to engage).

If one looks at the html generated for [Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644/) for the title and the url linked in the `<h1>` of the page, we get:

```
<title>Users who can&#39;t write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts - Meta Stack Exchange</title>
```

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
<a href="/questions/238644/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-%e2%89%a0-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts" class="question-hyperlink">Users who can&#39;t write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts</a>
</h1>
```

And while that's a long link title, I will point out that the quote as part of the word "can't" was removed from the slug.  The bug is that this should be done for *other* characters too.

Comment: so remove it...

Comment: @nicael ideally, I would contend that removal should be done as part of the url slug, though thats certainly debatable.  The diamond (and other characters that would require encoding) shouldn't be present in the url slug allowing a simple copy and paste of the url.  Alternatively, since this is the internal prettification tool, it could do a better job of recognizing the slug and process it accordingly.

Comment: ... from the Community ♦

Comment: Those are **not** ASCII characters, that's the whole issue. Did you mean Unicode instead, perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters other characters *are* removed from the automatically generated slug (such as the quote character) that would cause errors with parsing.  The bug is that it isn't removing enough other characters from the slug allowing issues with pasting the link in various systems.

Comment: Related (though not a dupe): [Replacement character being used question URL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240644)

Answer (score 18):

You are not pasting in a valid URL; although browser location bars may decode UTF-8 bytes for you, the proper way to encode those links is:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/my-question-was-deleted-by-community%E2%99%A6
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-%E2%99%A6-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-%E2%89%A0-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts
```

Note the `%E2%99%A6` three-byte UTF-8 encoding for the diamond, or the `%E2%89%A0` encoding not-equals (≠). I got these URLs simply by copying from the Chrome location bar, and they work as expected:

- [My question was deleted by Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129/my-question-was-deleted-by-community%E2%99%A6)
- [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/community-%E2%99%A6-should-discriminate-more-when-bumping-unanswered-questions)
- [Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644/users-who-cant-write-good-posts-%E2%89%A0-users-who-want-to-write-good-posts)

The URL parser is *correctly* not including the non-encoded diamond character in the URL, because valid URLs simply cannot include them.

Comment: Great answer, I have marked this [tag:status-bydesign]

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to mess with unicode at all. When linking to questions just omit the title:

```
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644
```

Results in:

- [My question was deleted by Community♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203129)
- [Community ♦ should discriminate more when bumping unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99672)
- [Users who can't write good posts ≠ users who want to write good posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238644)